# Running python in the terminal, syntax error

Tags: python, syntax, terminal

I'm trying to run a python program in the terminal. I have successfully called the .py script using `python filename.py`, and once the script starts running it asks for the first input file, which is a .csv file. When I type the path to that .csv file, I get a syntax error. See below for all the code starting with calling the python script.

```
python /Users/juliafiske/Desktop/GTSeq_Pipeline/Genotyping_Scripts/Genotyping_Scripts/GTseq_BarcodeSplit_MP_NextSeq_10K.py 

type the path to input file
Format= /home/user/...

/Users/juliafiske/Desktop/GTSeq_Pipeline/Practice/Practice_sampleIDs_new.csv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/juliafiske/Desktop/GTSeq_Pipeline/Genotyping_Scripts/Genotyping_Scripts/GTseq_BarcodeSplit_MP_NextSeq_10K.py", line 24, in <module>
    path1 = input()
  File "<string>", line 1
    /Users/juliafiske/Desktop/GTSeq_Pipeline/Practice/Practice_sampleIDs_new.csv
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The beginning of the .py script being called looks like this:

```
from multiprocessing import Process

print('type the path to input file\nFormat= /home/user/...')
path1 = input()

print('type the path to the fastq file to split\nFormat= /home/user/...')
path2 = input()
```

Comment: What happens if you put quotes around the input?

Comment: That worked!! Thank you so much. Such a simple fix, I'm a beginner!

Answer (score 3):

You're using Python 2.

Use `raw_input()` instead of `input()` to collect keyboard input.

Answer (score 1):

Quotations were needed around `/Users/juliafiske/....`